# Move file pointer to the end

Tags: c, file-handling

I am trying to make a students details record program in c wherein I will store all the data in a file.
I will provide the user with options such as entering a new record , display , etc.
How can i make the user input to be copied at the next line of the file?

Example :

## current file -->

Akshat 15 96

Roy 57 67

## user input -->

John as name

33 as USN

87 as marks

## final file output

Akshat 15 96

Roy 57 67

John 33 87

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open the file with append:
`file = fopen("myfile.txt", "a");`
Then write a newline and your text and close it.

Comment: Perfect, could you then please accept the answer, so everyone with the same problem knows that it got solved?

Comment: Done. Looked it up. Sorry , :) , didn't know about this accepting thing. But now I do. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try to open the file with "a" mode, example: `file=fopen("FileName.dat","a");`
and then fill it normally by reading the inputs from the user and then write them in your file:

example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
  char name[60];
  int age;
}E;
E temp;
/*lets say that the file is already filled and you want to append more data to it*/
int main (void) {
  FILE *file;
  file=fopen("FileName.dat","a");
  scanf("%s",temp.name);
  scanf("%d",&temp.age);
  //after you read the inputs from the user write the data into your file
  fwrite(&temp,sizeof(E),1,file);
  //dont forget to close the file
  fclose(file);
  return 0;
}
```